# Quality Check of a Brushless DC motor on an oscilloscope

Tags: dc-motor, oscilloscope, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase, waveform

I am Quality Checking some BLDC(Brushless DC) motors with an oscilloscope by connecting the BLDC to a drill, running it and viewing the output on my oscilloscope. I have been checking the Vpp(Peak to peak voltage) for the 3 phases and marking them good. Is there any other way to check the waveform and data to confirm the motor is good to go?

[image: Waveform of Motor]

[image: The Data]

Comment: Looks good to me. You can also test winding resistance and inductance. But BEMF is much more telling. You could double or halve the speed and the Vpp should follow. It's pretty difficult to find insulation degradation though since it might only spark through at higher voltages. The BEMF will find partial demagnetization if it is symmetric but you need a baseline to compare. Asymmetric demagnetization is easy...different Vpp between phases..

Comment: I think you should actually be using the motor as a motor and not exclusively as a generator if your are doing a QC test. What would your customers think if they weren't being tested as a motor under full load before being shipped?

Comment: Hi ... what is "QC"?

Comment: Quality Check .